# JavaScript Class with a Fixed Set of Instances

Tags: javascript, classes, enum

I am looking to write a JavaScript class `BasicType` with five fixed instances `INT`, `FLOAT`, `STRING`, `BOOL`, `ANYTHING`. It should be impossible to create any additional instances.

The instances themselves should have a single enumerable, non-configurable, non-writable property called `name`. Printing these instances with `console.log`, which delegates to `util.inspect`, should show the class name and name, for example:

```
> console.log(BasicType.BOOL)
BasicType { name: 'bool' }

> BasicType.BOOL.name = "zoolean"
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'name' of object '#<BasicType>'

> new BasicType("int")
Error: Basic type objects cannot be constructed
```

I've managed to make this work! Unfortunately my code is long and verbose and repetitive:

```
export class BasicType {
  static INT = Object.create(BasicType.prototype, {
    name: { value: "int", enumerable: true },
  });
  static FLOAT = Object.create(BasicType.prototype, {
    name: { value: "float", enumerable: true },
  });
  static BOOL = Object.create(BasicType.prototype, {
    name: { value: "bool", enumerable: true },
  });
  static STRING = Object.create(BasicType.prototype, {
    name: { value: "string", enumerable: true },
  });
  static ANYTHING = Object.create(BasicType.prototype, {
    name: { value: "anything", enumerable: true },
  });
  constructor() {
    throw new Error("Basic type objects cannot be constructed");
  }
}
```

The feedback I am looking for is:

- Is there a way to iterate through the five values? I don't see how since I have to declare the static properties. Maybe `defineProperties` (though this works with a single object) or maybe there is a static initializer construct?
- Is the throwing an error in the constructor the acceptable way to do this in JavaScript? Or is the very idea of fixing the number of instances antithetical to JavaScript?
- Is the `class` construct correct here? Maybe they should just be objects? I thought of this but then the `util.inspect` would have to be hacked to make it look like all the objects in the enclosing application (yes, it is a compiler), and doing type analysis with `.constructor` also would not work without hacking. So I kind of like using `class` here, but if there is a better way, I would love to see it.

I know this is ES2022 but Node and modern browsers already support `static` and I am fine using it. Any ES2022 forms are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand the purpose of this object `BasicType`.

You ask.

> *"Is there a way to iterate through the five values? "*

Yes using `Object.entries(BasicType)`

> *"Is the throwing an error in the constructor the acceptable way to do this in JavaScript?"*

No. In JS or any other language. Don't create a thing that has no purpose.

> *"Is the class construct correct here?"*

No, though I am unsure as to the purpose of `BasicType`

> *"Maybe they should just be objects? ... then the `util.inspect` would have to be hacked... ...and doing type analysis with .constructor also would not work without hacking..."*

Yes `class` defines a `function` (`typeof BasicType === "function"`) and a `function` is an `object`.

Why would `inspect` need to be hacked? `util.inspect` inspects objects.
And I don't know why you use a constructor to analysis type.

You can create a more robust object that can not be modified directly using `Object.freeze`

### Example

In example I create a class `BasicType` and a similar object called `BType`.
They look and act similarly however `BType` can not be changed while `BasicType` can not be trusted as the class syntax provides no security.

In the example I make `BType` a function. This is just to provide a similar constructor. Ideally if you did not need a constructor you would make the `BType` an object. see `BTypeO`

```js
class BasicType {
  static INT = Object.create(BasicType.prototype, {name: { value: "int", enumerable: true }});
  static FLOAT = Object.create(BasicType.prototype, {name: { value: "float", enumerable: true }});
  constructor() { throw new Error("Basic type objects cannot be constructed"); }
}

const BType = (()=> {
    const name = (name) => Object.freeze({name: name.toLowerCase()})
    return Object.freeze( Object.assign(function (){ throw new Error("Foo bar") },  
        ["INT","FLOAT"].reduce((obj, type) => (obj[type] = name(type), obj), {}
    )));
})();

// As typeof object. Example only
const BTypeO = (()=> {
    const name = (name) => Object.freeze({name: name.toLowerCase()})
    return Object.freeze(["INT","FLOAT"].reduce((obj, type) => (obj[type] = name(type), obj), {}));
})();

// Proxy handler to replace unprotected identifiers (eg BasicType)
const proxyHdlr = {get(t, p) {console.log("Proxy trapping ", p); return {name: "foo"}}};

console.log("--General properties BasicType, BType------------------------");
console.log("BasicType is typeof " + typeof BasicType);
console.log("BType is typeof " + typeof BType);

console.log("Iterate BasicType", Object.entries(BasicType) + "");
console.log("Iterate BType", Object.entries(BType) + "");

try{ new BasicType() } catch(e) { console.log("BasicType constructor error: " + e.message) }
try{ new BType() } catch(e) { console.log("BType constructor error: " + e.message) }


console.log("--Accessing BasicType------------------------");
BasicType.INT.name =  "monkeys";
console.log("BasicType.INT.name = " + BasicType.INT.name);  // Still here
delete BasicType.INT;  // can delete
try{ console.log(BasicType.INT.name) } catch(e){ console.log(e.message) }; // will throw error as INT is undefined
BasicType.INT = {name: "monkey"};  // can modify / replace / alter
console.log("BasicType.INT.name = " + BasicType.INT.name);
BasicType = new Proxy(BasicType, proxyHdlr);  // class name is writable and can silently be trapped
console.log("BasicType.FLOAT.name = " + BasicType.FLOAT.name);  // all access is now named foo

console.log("--Accessing BType------------------------");
BType.INT.name =  "monkeys";  // can not rename 
console.log("BType.INT.name = " + BType.INT.name);  // Still here
delete BType.INT;     // can not delete
console.log("BType.INT.name = " + BType.INT.name);  // Still here
BType.INT = {name: "monkey"};  // can not assign
console.log("BType.INT.name = " + BType.INT.name);  // Still here
try{ BType = new Proxy(BType, proxyHdlr)} catch(e){ console.log("assign to BType error: " + e.message) }; // is const and can not overwrite
console.log("BType.FLOAT.name = " + BType.FLOAT.name);
```